# Mysql - update t1 with count of t2 rows where two columns are the same as for t1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`, and would like to get as output t1 with an added column giving the count of rows in t2 where (id, category) are present.

Here is an example on a small data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `t1` (`key`, `id`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 12, 101),
(2, 12, 104),
(3, 13, 102),
(4, 14, 101),
(5, 15, 102);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `t2` (`key`, `id`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 12, 101),
(2, 12, 102),
(3, 13, 101),
(4, 13, 104),
(5, 12, 101),
(6, 15, 102);
```

Here is the **output I wish to have**, the last column being the desired infos:

```
t1 updated
key, id, category, count_t2_id_category
1, 12, 101, 2     # because (12,101) appears 2 times in t2
2, 12, 104, 0     # because (12,104) appears 0 times in t2
3, 13, 102, 0     # etc
4, 14, 101, 0
5, 15, 102, 1
```

I tried the following command to start with, but it misses some t1 rows in the output:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.category = t2.category
GROUP BY t1.id
```

output missing t1 key #2:

```
key id  category    key id  category    
1   12  101 1   12  101 
3   13  102 NULL    NULL    NULL    
4   14  101 NULL    NULL    NULL    
5   15  102 6   15  102
```

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, so I'm not sure why you have included a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want zero values for your non-matched rows, it's a work for `LEFT JOIN`, like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  IF(t2.`key` IS NULL, 0, COUNT(t1.`key`)) AS t2_row_count 
FROM 
  t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 
      ON t1.id=t2.id 
      AND 
      t1.category=t2.category 
GROUP BY 
  t1.`key`
```

We're counting `t1.key` because for matched rows they will be same in *first* table (and not second) - thus, we should group by it - and not by field in second table.

*Tip*: avoid to name your tables/columns with mysql reserved words. This will save you lots of time if you'll accidentally forget backticks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please change your column name key to recid coz key is a reserved word of mysql

SELECT t1.recid, t1.id, t1.category, count(t2.category) as count FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.category = t2.category GROUP BY t1.id,t1.category