# R - update t1 with count of t2 rows where two columns are the same as for t1

Tags: r

I have two tables, and would like to get as output t1 with an added column giving the count of rows in t2 where (id, category) are present.
Here is an example on a small data set:

```
id = c(12,12,13,14,15)
category = c(101,104,102,101,102)
t1 = cbind(id, category)

id = c(12,12,13,13,12,15)
category = c(101,102,101,104,101,102)
t2 = cbind(id, category)

> t1
     id category
[1,] 12      101
[2,] 12      104
[3,] 13      102
[4,] 14      101
[5,] 15      102
> t2
     id category
[1,] 12      101
[2,] 12      102
[3,] 13      101
[4,] 13      104
[5,] 12      101
[6,] 15      102
```

**I wish to obtain t1 updated with counts of (id, category) in t2**:

```
> t1
      id  category  count_id_cat_in_t2
[1,]  12       101  2        # because (12,101) appears 2 times in t2
[2,]  12       104  0        # because (12,104) appears 0 times in t2
[3,]  13       102  0        # etc
[4,]  14       101  0
[5,]  15       102  1
```

Since I work with a large data set, I need a solution that can do this under 5 minutes if possible for **large data set**:

- t1 has 300 thousands rows
- t2 has  15 million rows

I have this working in MySQL based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490584/190791), but could not port it into R using sqldf.
I am working on Windows and could not get the library needed to use MySQL commands with sqldf.

Answer (score 1):

The dplyr solution from beginnR works, but took too long for the whole data set (I stopped it after 50 minutes).

I found a fast solution with **data table binary search**:

```
id = c(12,12,13,14,15)
category = c(101,104,102,101,102)
t1 = data.frame(id, category)

id = c(12,12,13,13,12,15)
category = c(101,102,101,104,101,102)
t2 = data.frame(id, category)

library(data.table)
t2 = data.table(t2)
setkey(t2, id, category) # setting key, preparing for a FAST binary search

n = dim(t1)[1]
counts <- array(NA, n)

for(i in(1:n))
{
    id_ = t1$id[i]
    category_ = t1$category[i]

    counts[i] = dim(t2[J(id_, category_),nomatch=0])[1] # data table FAST binary search
}

t1$count_id_cat_in_tr = counts
```

This works in 5/10 minutes for the large data set (t1:150 thousand rows, t2: 15 million rows).

---

Another way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
setDT(t1)
setkey(setDT(t2), id, category)
ans = t2[t1, .N]

# or a little faster
ans = t2[t1][, .N, by="id,category"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Here is an sqldf solution:

```
sqldf(c("create index i on df2(id, category)", "select A.*, coalesce(count, 0) count
       from df1 A 
       left natural join 
          (select *, count(*) count from main.df2 group by id, category)"))
```

giving:

```
  id category count
1 12      101     2
2 12      104     0
3 13      102     0
4 14      101     0
5 15      102     1
```

Omit the indexing if speed is jnot an issue in which case replace `main.df2` with `df2`.

**2)** The `RMySQL` package works under Windows. I ran the following using RMySQL and sqldf under Windows. See `?sqldf` for more info on using sqldf with MySQL.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RMySQL)
sqldf(c("create index i on df2(id, category)", 
      "select A.*, coalesce(kount, 0) count
       from df1 A 
       left join 
          (select *, count(*) kount from df2 group by id, category) B
       on A.id = B.id and A.category = B.category"))
```

or use the SQL statement that you already have working.  This gives:

```
id category count
1 12      101     2
2 12      104     0
3 13      102     0
4 14      101     0
5 15      102     1
```

Answer (score 0):

using dplyr you could do the following:

```
id = c(12,12,13,14,15)
category = c(101,104,102,101,102)
t1 = data.frame(id, category)     #data.frame format

id = c(12,12,13,13,12,15)
category = c(101,102,101,104,101,102)
t2 = data.frame(id, category)     #data.frame format

require(dplyr)

t1 <- t1 %.%
  group_by(id, category) %.%
  summarize(count_id_cat_in_t2 = sum(t2$category == category & t2$id == id))
```

note that t1 and t2 are created as `data.frame`s

Comment: Thank you. It is working on the small exampel above. I am testing on the large data set. It has been running for 5 minutes now...

Comment: since your t2 dataframe has 15 million rows, this is perhaps not surprising. there may be a faster solution with data.table (?) i think in general, dplyr speed is not too bad, see e.g. [link](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/09/a-speed-test-comparison-of-plyr-data-table-and-dplyr/)

Comment: FYI I found another way, much faster it seems, with data table binary search (see my answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plyr solution (I'm not sure if it's fast)

```
library(plyr)

id = c(12,12,13,14,15)
category = c(101,104,102,101,102)
t1 = data.frame(id, category)

id = c(12,12,13,13,12,15)
category = c(101,102,101,104,101,102)
t2 = data.frame(id, category)

t3 <- join(t1,
           ddply(t2, .(id, category), c("nrow")),
           by=c("id", "category"))
t3$nrow[is.na(t3$nrow)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `eat` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), add a constant column to `t2` and agregate it as we join it to `t1`.

Using data frames as in other answers:

```
# # devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
# library(safejoin)

eat(t1, mutate(t2, n=1), n, .agg = sum) %>%
  mutate(n = replace(n, is.na(n), 0))
#   id category n
# 1 12      101 2
# 2 12      104 0
# 3 13      102 0
# 4 14      101 0
# 5 15      102 1
```